# Display results without repeat depending on other tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to solve a problem but i didn't even know how to ask it, so sorry for the title.

Please be patient and try to understand, thank you.

I have this tables, and the corresponding fields:

users - list of users

```
user_id | user_name (...)
```

classes - list of classes

```
class_id | class_name (...)
```

posts - list of posts

```
post_id | post_title (...)
```

uclass - this table has the list of classes that each user has access

```
uclass_id | class_id | user_id
```

pclass - this table has the list of posts that each class has access

```
pclass_id | post_id | class_id
```

Users can have access to several classes.
And Posts can be accessed by several classes.

So I need to get the list of posts that the user has access to. That just happend when user has access to a class and this one has access to a post.

I tryed to do this using LEFT JOIN the problem is that because users can have access to several class and several classes can have access to the same post, the result is that some posts appear several times.

What is the best way to do this without repeated results.

I hope you understand what i need.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I tryed lots of ways, this was one:

```
SELECT * FROM post
LEFT JOIN pclass ON post.post_id = pclass.post_id
LEFT JOIN uclass ON uclass.user_id = 'USERDEMOUSER'
WHERE uclass.class_id = pclass.class_id
```

I know something is missing but i can't find what it is...or perhaps it should be done in a totally different way!

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and consider setting up a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post.post_id (etc.)
```

This will work similar to GROUP BY, but in a better way.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM post
LEFT JOIN pclass ON post.post_id = pclass.post_id
LEFT JOIN uclass ON uclass.class_id = pclass.class_id
WHERE uclass.user_id = 'USERDEMOUSER'
```

Comment: sory but it repeats the same result...same problem. Thank you.

Comment: please, send an exemple of the error and the possible correct result

Comment: you need to use group by, like this:
SELECT * FROM post
LEFT JOIN pclass ON post.post_id = pclass.post_id
LEFT JOIN uclass ON uclass.class_id = pclass.class_id
WHERE uclass.user_id = 'USERDEMOUSER'
GROUP BY uclass.user_id

Comment: Nice idea, and i also tryed that, but i can't :) Because I'm creating a paging system to present the results. So first i need to count the results and GROUP BY is not good.

Comment: use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. example here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i found the right solution. Check my answer.